# Function Call ambiguity in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following functions

```
void foo(int const &a, long const &b)
{
  std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
}

void foo(int &&a, long &&b)
{
  std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
}

...
// Some where in main(), we called
foo(5.0, 3.5f);
```

The output will be C, as r-value reference are given priority on r-values.
However, if I have the following function added in.

```
void foo(int a, char b)
{
  std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}
```

The whole thing will be ambiguous.

- A vs B = Ambiguous
- A vs C = Ambiguous

Hope I can seek help for someone to explain this, thank you.

Comment: Just don't introduce ambiguities on purpose?

Comment: Ask yourself: Which function should the compiler choose?

Comment: Binding to a reference and to a non-reference are both exact matches, so neither is a better overload than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I just realized, because the 2nd argument for all 3 functions have to be converted from float to their respective argument types. Silly me